# Connect in-built microphone in webcam through USB

Tags: usb, microphone

I recently repurposed a webcam from a HP laptop to make it USB webcam. I was able to connect the webcam to USB. It also has an in-built microphone, and I dont know how to make it usable. 
The webcam had 6 connections - D+, D-, Power (5V), GND, L, R. I connected D+, D-, Power & GND to corresponding wires in a USB and got the webcam working. Now I'm left with 2 wires - which is L & R for the mic. I don't know how to connect this to the same USB wire or a different USB. I read somewhere that, these integrated microphones use the same GND as the webcam. Other than that, I have no clue. Seeking help from the experts. The webcam is one of those from Silicon Motion Inc, used in DV4 series of HP Pavilion Notebook PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's not designed to go into any USB cable - it's designed to go into the MIC input of the laptop's sound card.  So you'll need to connect it to a sound card to use with a computer.

Comment: Thanks Grant. I'm trying to connect this to Raspberry Pi, which doesn't have a sound card or a mic input. Does it mean that I'll have to buy a sound card (that has USB interface on other end to connect to Pi?)